# Spring boot actuator trying to make DB connection

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot application written using jhipster that was handed to our project not long ago.  It's been running under WebLogic and I'm in the process of moving it to Tomcat9, getting ready for cloud migration.  I found that when I access actuator's **"health"**, the application returned {"status" : "DOWN"} and it was attempting to connect to the database.

**I don't want it to attempt the connection.**  I tried looking through the application but found no setting that seems to be causing this.  I'm sure it's there somewhere, though.

Does anyone have any idea where I should look?

The following exception was thrown:

```
2020-04-13 07:41:32.003 ERROR 16156 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Why deploying in tomcat? Have you considered using embedded tomcat as this is the deployment model recommended by JHipster team? The connection attempt do db from actuator health is not triggered by JHipster code, it looks more like Spring Boot default behavior as Simon Martinelli said; see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: Eventually it will go to OCP.  Deploying to Tomcat is just to make sure that it can run under Tomcat, nothing to it.  The next step is to put that into Docker and then go to Openshift.

Comment: Docker and executable jar go very well together

Comment: It's just a step in our process.  The Docker team will do whatever they need to do.  I just need to get it to run in Tomcat. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB health check is enabled when you add actuator framework.

You can disable the db health check with this property:

```
management.health.db.enabled=false
```

Read more about all the actuator properties here: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator-properties